# Split power across three circuits with difrerent resistance and provide equal current

Tags: batteries, resistors

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKPzK3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Me and a friend are working on a project and have three circuits with resistance (8.9k ohm) across them and a single 9v battery. We need to pass 9v along at least two of the circuits at once in full DC, so we can't PWM it. How can we do this? Every circuit only draws 1 mA but they need to stay at 9v each.

Comment: Welcome to electronics.stackexchange! Please use the integrated drawing tool for circuits or draw it in another way and attach it as a picture. As of now your question is unclear. The way the three circuits are connected must be guessed.

Answer (score 1):

Powering each individual circuit in parallel  from the battery would provide ~9VDC (depending on battery charge) to the Vin of each circuit.

Comment: But as the other circuit opens (They open and close dependant on a sensor) the current would be split among them. We need the same amount of power going through all the circuits, as if there where 3 separate batteries powering the circuit. Each one has about 8.9 Kohm and we need 1 milliamp going in at 9v through each one. Would a DC-DC converter and a higher voltage battery work?